# Limit chars to show at input html tag

Tags: html

How can I limit the chars to show at a input tag?
I'm getting from the server the time with this format: `hh:mm:ss`, and I want to show something with this format `hh:mm`, there are a way to get it?

I tried with maxlength, size on chrome, but I can't get it..

```
<input id="timetable_start" name="start" type="text" value="07:31:00" maxlength=5 pattern="^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$" size=5>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8FtAX/

Comment: You can't do this in HTML alone. Either change the server script that creates the HTML, or use Javascript to fix the page up after it's generated.

Comment: Agreed.  It's kind of backwards to output something to the markup and then try to change it.  Just output the desired content in the first place.

Comment: Add the code you use to get the time for the server, as the changes need to be implemented at that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have control over the incoming data, you can use javascript to show that you want, with jquery + timeentry.js you can do it easily and also get more functionality:

```
$(function () {
    $("#timetable_start").timeEntry({show24Hours: true});
});
```

Try here: http://jsfiddle.net/cespinoza/e3anw/10/

Answer (score 1):

It is working.

Try changing the initial value, from:

```
value="07:31:00"
```

to:

```
value="07:31"
```

Comment: The input value comes from the server side (python), I can't change it

Comment: You can't change the initial value, but you do can change the HTML page? If that's the case, you can add a javascript snippet that will truncate the input values.

Answer (score 0):

You should really process the data server-side (e.g., by truncating strings to specific length), so that the data in the HTML document is what you want to show. But if this is impossible, you can use the `size` attribute to specify the visible width of a text input box in characters (as you have tried) *and* set the font to monospace, e.g. with

```
size="5" style="font-family: Consolas, Lucida Console, monospace"
```

added to the `input` tag. The point is that “(average) width of a character” has no definite meaning except for a monospace font, and browsers traditionally implement the `size` attribute in rather different ways, except for monospace fonts.

However, note that the form data, as sent upon submission, available to client-side scripting, and checked with the browser if it supports the `pattern` attribute would still initially be what you have placed in the `value` attribute. So the user would need to guess this and remove the “invisible” part. This sounds like usability nightmare.